# optimization approach in logistic regression

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, classification, optimization

In logistic regression we need to maximise the log likelihood which boils down to minimising a function which is sum of multiple log functions. We normally use gradient descent approach there. Can we use normal differentiation approach ?

Answer (score 1):

The point is to find the parameters that maximize the likelihood function, how you do it is inconsequential. So, yes you can use any algorithm that you find convenient.

Comment: Agreed, but I think the OP is asking if there is a closed-form solution obtainable by calculus, to which the answer is definitely No.

Comment: As always, Nick is right, but there are exceptions. There is a closed form solution when one only has categorical explanatory variables and the model is fully saturated, i.e. includes all the (higher order) interaction terms.

Comment: Point well taken! (In statistics, almost all answers exclude possibilities of measure (almost) zero.)

Comment: Why wont we get a closed form solution ? @NickCox

Comment: Look at the equation for the likelihood function, or its logarithm. Now see if you can rearrange it to get such a solution.